# Form onSubmit validation not working

Tags: javascript, validation

I want to use javascript to validate my form's input before sending the data to the php file. I tried using `onSubmit`, but for some reason the javascript function is getting skipped over and the data is going straight to the php file. I'm not sure what's wrong with my code- I'd initially put the javascript in another file, then I included it in the page itself with a `<script>` tag, it's still not working. Here's my code-

The form-

```
<form action="includes/register.inc.php" name="registration_form" method="post" onSubmit="return regform(this.form,
 this.form.first-name, this.form.last-name, this.form.signup-username, this.form.signup-email, 
this.form.signup-password, this.form.confirm-password);">

    <input id="first-name" name="first-name" type="text" placeholder="First Name"/>
    <input id="last-name" name="last-name" type="text" placeholder="Last Name"/>
    <input id="signup-username" name="signup-username" type="text" placeholder="Username"/>
    <input id="signup-email" name="signup-email" type="email" placeholder="E-mail"/>
    <input id="signup-password" name="signup-password" type="password"  placeholder="Password"/>
    <input id="confirm-password" type="password" name="confirm-password" placeholder="Confirm Password"/>

    <input type="submit" value="CREATE ACCOUNT"/>
</form>
```

Javascript-

```
function regform(form, fname, lname, uid, email, password, conf) {
 // Check each field has a value
if (uid.value == ''         || 
      email.value == ''     || 
      password.value == ''  || 
      fname.value == ''     ||
      lname.value == ''     ||
      conf.value == '') {

    alert('You must provide all the requested details. Please try again');
    return false;
}

// Check the username

re = /^\w+$/; 
if(!re.test(uid.value)) { 
    alert("Username must contain only letters, numbers and underscores. Please try again"); 

    return false; 
}

var alphaExp = /^[a-zA-Z\-]+$/;
if(!fname.value.match(alphaExp)) { 
    alert("First name must contain only letters and hyphens. Please try again"); 

    return false; 
}

if(!lname.value.match(alphaExp)) { 
    alert("First name must contain only letters and hyphens. Please try again"); 

    return false; 
}

// Check that the password is sufficiently long (min 6 chars)
// The check is duplicated below, but this is included to give more
// specific guidance to the user
if (password.value.length < 6) {
    alert('Passwords must be at least 6 characters long.  Please try again');

    return false;
}

// At least one number, one lowercase and one uppercase letter 
// At least six characters 

var re = /(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,}/; 
if (!re.test(password.value)) {
    alert('Passwords must contain at least one number, one lowercase and one uppercase letter.  Please try again');
    return false;
}

// Check password and confirmation are the same
if (password.value != conf.value) {
    alert('Your password and confirmation do not match. Please try again');

    return false;
}


// Finally submit the form. 
return true;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any php here.

Comment: I didn't include the php code because that's not the problem- the js function is just getting skipped over, and the form is getting submitted no matter what I enter.

Comment: your function parameters have `-` sign

Comment: then don't tag it as such; it makes the post unclear and is misleading for those who follow that tag.

Comment: What should `this.form` in the `onClick` do?

Comment: Error message in the console should point out you are doing calculations, not dealing with ids. dot notation can not deal with `-`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not `this.form`, since `this` already refers to the form. also you need to use brackets for any properties that contain a hyphen as JS will think it's a minus sign. `this['last-name']`

Comment: Thanks, it's working now! And yeah, I changed the hyphens to underscores

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Instead of pass a bunch of params to the function, I'm passing the form itself, then pulling out values from there.

```js
function regform(form) {
  // Check each field has a value
  if (form['signup-username'].value == '' ||
    form['signup-email'].value == '' ||
    form['signup-password'].value == '' ||
    form['first-name'].value == '' ||
    form['last-name'].value == '' ||
    form['confirm-password'].value == '') {

    alert('You must provide all the requested details. Please try again');
    return false;
  }

  // Check the username

  re = /^\w+$/;
  if (!re.test(uid.value)) {
    alert("Username must contain only letters, numbers and underscores. Please try again");

    return false;
  }

  var alphaExp = /^[a-zA-Z\-]+$/;
  if (!fname.value.match(alphaExp)) {
    alert("First name must contain only letters and hyphens. Please try again");

    return false;
  }

  if (!lname.value.match(alphaExp)) {
    alert("First name must contain only letters and hyphens. Please try again");

    return false;
  }

  // Check that the password is sufficiently long (min 6 chars)
  // The check is duplicated below, but this is included to give more
  // specific guidance to the user
  if (password.value.length < 6) {
    alert('Passwords must be at least 6 characters long.  Please try again');

    return false;
  }

  // At least one number, one lowercase and one uppercase letter 
  // At least six characters 

  var re = /(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,}/;
  if (!re.test(password.value)) {
    alert('Passwords must contain at least one number, one lowercase and one uppercase letter.  Please try again');
    return false;
  }

  // Check password and confirmation are the same
  if (password.value != conf.value) {
    alert('Your password and confirmation do not match. Please try again');

    return false;
  }


  // Finally submit the form. 
  return true;
}
```

```html
<form action="" name="registration_form" method="post" onSubmit="return regform(this);">

  <input id="first-name" name="first-name" type="text" placeholder="First Name" />
  <input id="last-name" name="last-name" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" />
  <input id="signup-username" name="signup-username" type="text" placeholder="Username" />
  <input id="signup-email" name="signup-email" type="email" placeholder="E-mail" />
  <input id="signup-password" name="signup-password" type="password" placeholder="Password" />
  <input id="confirm-password" type="password" name="confirm-password" placeholder="Confirm Password" />

  <input type="submit" value="CREATE ACCOUNT" />
</form>
```